# Why AppCompatResources.getDrawable(Context context, int resId) marked as @Nullable

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-appcompat, android-resources

AppCompatResources.getDrawable probably returns null if resource id is invalid, or links to something other then drawable. Is there any other reason getDrawable(context, resid) returns null?

I sometimes encounter such code, is null check reasonable here?:

```
initToolbar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.ic_close_24dp);
    //is there any reason to check for null    
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.setColorFilter(ColorUtil.getColorPrimary(requireContext()), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
    } else {
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(ic_close_primary_24dp);
    }
}
```

The reason such code appears is that studio will raise a warning on code like this:

```
mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_24_close);
mToolbar.getNavigationIcon().setColorFilter(filter); //warning here, but should I react to it?
```

Comment: Yes, it returns **null** in case of `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Comment: @JeelVankhede is it possible if resource id is valid?

Comment: If resource is valid then it provides you `drawable` else **null** if something went wrong like `ResourceNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable()` can return `null`:

```
    public Drawable getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId,
            boolean failIfNotKnown) {
        checkVectorDrawableSetup(context);
        Drawable drawable = loadDrawableFromDelegates(context, resId);
        if (drawable == null) {
            drawable = createDrawableIfNeeded(context, resId);
        }
        if (drawable == null) {
            drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resId);
        }
        if (drawable != null) {
            // Tint it if needed
            drawable = tintDrawable(context, resId, failIfNotKnown, drawable);
        }
        if (drawable != null) {
            // See if we need to 'fix' the drawable
            DrawableUtils.fixDrawable(drawable);
        }
        return drawable;
    }
```

Comment: yes I know it can, but should i check for null if I am sure that resouce is valid? is there some situation in system when valid resource can't be exctracted and fails with ResourceNotFoundException?